# How to create a table inside a cell in itextsharp(Nested table) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

How to create a nested table inside a cell in asp.net in ITextSharp.
I have a Maintable inside a Maintable cell i want to create a table in itextsharp i asp.net .

```
     PdfPTable Maintable = new PdfPTable(2);
 phrase = new Phrase();
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase()); 
 PdfPTable tbaleassis = new PdfPTable(2);
  PdfPCell cellasss = new PdfPCell();
        Phrase phra = new Phrase();
int rowindex1 = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row1 in gvSkills.Rows)
        {
            TextBox t1 = (TextBox)gvSkills.Rows[rowindex1].Cells[1].FindControl("txtskils1");
            string asa = t1.Text;

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(asa, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL));
            phra.Add(p1);
            rowindex1++;
        }

        tbaleassis.AddCell(phra);
        int rowindex2 = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row1 in gvSkills.Rows)
        {
            TextBox t1 = (TextBox)gvSkills.Rows[rowindex2].Cells[2].FindControl("txtskils2");
            string asa = t1.Text;
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(asa, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL));

            phra.Add(p1);
            rowindex2++;
        }
        tbaleassis.AddCell(phra);
        cellasss = new PdfPCell(tbaleassis);

        table.AddCell(cellasss);
        ds.Add(Maintable);
```

Comment: It is a little hard to follow your code.  A few comments might help. Then more people might respond.  Is PdfPTable a DataTable and ds is a dataset?

Comment: @tgolisch Do u understand mt Question???

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie Pls Reply

Answer (score 0):

You declare a "Maintable" but at the end of your code you are adding your content to a whatever "table" and then add the empty Maintable to your document.

So fix your

```
table.AddCell(cellasss);
```

line and btw init that Maintable with just 1 row, if you are ever adding only one cell.

And please get some consistent style on your variable names!